# Azure Storage SDK for Blob storage - How to set the expiration date of a blob relative to the current time

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I can see from the Azure Storage [REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id#expiryoption), that it is possible to set the expiration date of a blob at the time it is created.

Is it possible to set a newly created blob's expiration date via the Azure Blob Storage client library for .NET?

If someone has an example or link to more information, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set a newly created blob's expiration date via the Azure Blob Storage client library for .NET?

You can use the below code to set the expiration date of a blob relative to the current time with the **`request`** method using C#.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net";
        string containerName = "test";
        string blobName = "demo.png";
        string SAStoken = "sp=w&st=2023-11-14T07:16:20Z&se=2023-11-14T15:16:20Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig==xxxxx"; //write permission
        DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, new Uri($"{url}/{containerName}/{blobName}?comp=expiry&{SAStoken}"));
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2020-02-10");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-expiry-time", "60000"); //one minute
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-expiry-option", "RelativeTonow");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dt.ToString("R"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expiry Time added to the blob successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code adds an expiry time as a sample of (one minute) to a blob in Azure Blob Storage using a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token. The code creates an HTTP PUT request to the blob URL with the expiry time specified in the request headers.

**Output:**

```
Expiry Time added to the blob successfully
```

[image]

The above code operation is allowed only on **`hierarchical namespace`** enabled storage accounts.

**Reference:**
[Set Blob Expiry (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-expiry?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, appreciated.  However,  I was hoping there would be something available in the .Net Storage SDK, i.e.: via the BlobClient object, but I guess using the REST API is the only way.  I also didn't realize the operation is allowed on hierarchical namespace-enabled accounts only - which mine is not.

Comment: @bdcoder yes, I think only possible way is rest api and the operation is allowed for only hierarchical namespace enables accounts only.