# java.lang.NullPointerException: The argument must not be null or an empty string. Argument name: storageSharedKeyCredentials

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to store a blob in Azure Blob Storage and delete it after certain time, like a minute or two. I've successfully configured the uploading process. It's uploading with proper metadata, but the issue is I can generate the sasToken properly for that blob, for the given time-range. And I went to Azure Blob Store to check if it is getting deleted after a minute or not, turns out now.

So my question is pretty simply, how can I set expiration of a blob when uploading? And how to generate the sas-token correctly?

Here is the code below:

```java
public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();

        BlobContainerSasPermission permissions = new BlobContainerSasPermission()
                .setReadPermission(true)
                .setWritePermission(true)
                .setCreatePermission(true)
                .setDeletePermission(false);
        OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sasValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permissions);

        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(file.getOriginalFilename());

        BlobHttpHeaders jsonHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
        BinaryData data = BinaryData.fromStream(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
        BlobParallelUploadOptions options = new BlobParallelUploadOptions(data)
                .setRequestConditions(
                        new BlobRequestConditions()
                ).setHeaders(jsonHeaders);
        blobClient.uploadWithResponse(options, null, Context.NONE);

        String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(blobClient.getBlobUrl() + "?", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String sasToken = blobContainerClient.generateSas(sasValues);

        return result + sasToken;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's raising an exception saying:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: The argument must not be null or an
> empty string. Argument name: storageSharedKeyCredentials.

Comment: Hi, @Maifee UI Asad Either you need to generate the SAS token within 1 minute or your blob need to be deleted after 1 minute?

Comment: my blob needs to be deleted after 1 minute @Venkatesan

Comment: Refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-expiry?tabs=microsoft-entra-id if you need to set expiration blob. This operation is allowed only on hierarchical namespace-enabled accounts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475629/azure-storage-sdk-for-blob-storage-how-to-set-the-expiration-date-of-a-blob-re this one C# how to set the expiration date of a blob relative to the current time.

Comment: Please provide the exception stacktrace, not just the exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My blob needs to be deleted after 1 minute & How can I set the expiration of a blob?

You can use the [MS-Dcoument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell,managed-identity,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli#upload-blobs-to-a-container) to upload the file from the local environment to Azure storage. To set an expiration, you need **`hierarchical namespace-enabled`** storage accounts.

In my environment, I uploaded a file with the name **`goodone.jpg`** in my container.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below code to set expiration with the **`Rest API`** process using Java.

**Code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://<Storage account name >.blob.core.windows.net";
        String containerName = "test";
        String blobName = "goodone.jpg";
        String SAStoken = "sp=w&st=2023-12-06T07:02:08Z&se=2023-12-06T15:02:08Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxx"; //write permission
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .build();
                

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .PUT(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .uri(URI.create(url + "/" + containerName + "/" + blobName + "?comp=expiry&" + SAStoken))
                .header("x-ms-version", "2020-02-10")
                .header("x-ms-expiry-time", "60000") //one minute
                .header("x-ms-expiry-option", "RelativeTonow")
                .header("x-ms-date", now.toString())
                .build();

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("Expiry Time added to the blob successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: " + response.statusCode() + " - " + response.body());
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Expiry Time added to the blob successfully
```

[image]

After executing the code, I verified from the portal the blob was deleted after 1 minute successfully.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Set Blob Expiry (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-expiry?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)

Comment: It works, which is absolutely fine.. really appreciate it... But I was amazed that the method wrapper raises exceptions.. but we can always implement it this way... Thanks